# Convert values from a key to uppercase

Tags: python, dictionary

Here I have an dictionary and I want to make some values uppercase.

```
# Create a dictionary
another_dictionary = {"numbers": [1, 2, 3], "letters":["a", "b", "c"], "codes":[123, 456, 789]}
```

I want to convert all the values from letters to be uppercase. I've tried many methods but none of them worked.

First try:

```
for letters in another_dictionary["letters"]:
letters = letters.upper()
print(letters)
```

Second try:

```
another_dictionary.update({k.lower(): v.upper() for k, v in another_dictionary["letters"].item()})
print(another_dictionary["letters"])
```

Last try:

```
dict((v.lower(), v) for k,v in another_dictionary["letters"].lower())
```

Comment: How about: 
d['letters'] = [letter.upper() for letter in d['letters']]

Comment: Hi vcosmin2701, would you please specify what you desired output in your answer. As of now, it's currently unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This evaluates to what it seems like you want:

```
dict((k, v if k != "letters" else [x.upper() for x in v]) for k,v in another_dictionary.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you? First you adress the `key` that contains `letters` and replace the value with a list comprehension in which you apply `upper` to the original values in `another_dictionary['letters']` values:

```
another_dictionary = {"numbers":[1, 2, 3], "letters":["a", "b", "c"], "codes":[123, 456, 789]}
another_dictionary['letters']  = [x.upper() for x in another_dictionary['letters']]

print(another_dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'letters': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'codes': [123, 456, 789]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are simply trying to update an array of letters, you can use Python's list comprehension feature onto the array:

```
another_dictonary["letters"] = [letter.upper() for letter in another_dictonary["letters"]]
```

You can find more information on how list comprehension works in Python [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).